# nestjs import dynamic modules

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I use loading providers using `fast-glob`.

```
fg
    .sync("src/domain/**/*.service.ts")
    .map((file) => path.join(process.cwd(), file))
    .map((service) => require(service)["default"]);
```

It includes `AService`,`BService`

And I added

```
import AService from "./AService";
import BService from "./BService";

...
const arr = fg
    .sync("src/domain/**/*.service.ts")
    .map((file) => path.join(process.cwd(), file))
    .map((service) => require(service)["default"]);

console.log(arr.includes(AService));
```

I tested it on local. and display true.
But if i test it on docker, display false.
What is difference?

This is tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2019", "DOM"],
    "target": "es2019",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "isolatedModules": true
  }
}
```

Here is dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.5-buster

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn cache clean

RUN yarn install

COPY . .

RUN yarn build

CMD ["node", "-r", "ts-node/register", "-r", "tsconfig-paths/register", "./dist/main.js"]
```

Comment: What's your docker setup look like?

Comment: probably not related but wouldn't `COPY . .` overwrite the containers `node_modules` dir with your local version? `COPY dist ./` or similar should only copy that part. Is the commandline the same when testing locally? i.e. `node -r ts-node/register -r tsconfig-paths/register ./dist/main.js` - `src/domain/` may need to become `dist/domain/` and I don't think tsconfig-paths can do that for you (I don't see what it does at all, "load modules whose location is specified in the paths section of tsconfig.json" and you don't have that)

Comment: And then why `ts-node/register` when you have a js compiled `dist` folder? You don't need to execute ts files, they would be .js which might explain why your fast-glob code can load the ts file (and you copy src as well with that `COPY . .` I guess) but it's different from the js file version loaded by `from "./AService";`

Comment: thanks zapi. `src/domain/**/*.service.ts` should be `dist/domain/`.
Solved.